# updating jsonb field in postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, json, postgresql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a value in a jsonb column in postgresql.

```
// column 'settings'
{
  "country": "us",
  "language": "en"
}
```

I want to use prepared statements and I want to update a specific value, so not the whole jsonb object.

This does not work:

```
UPDATE users SET settings = jsonb_set(settings, '{country}', '$1'::jsonb)
```

I'm trying to cast the value of the prepared statement to jsonb, it does not work. Error is `invalid input syntax for type json`.

What is the correct way to update specific values in a jsonb field.

I'm using nodejs pg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following syntax should work in a prepared statement

```
UPDATE users SET settings = jsonb_set(settings, '{country}', to_jsonb($1::text))
```